# Building kernel from deb-src - missing modules?

Tags: kernel, compiling

I'm trying to build a kernel from the Ubuntu package source on Mantic.  So far, I've done this:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep linux linux-image-generic
$ sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev gawk flex bison openssl libssl-dev dkms libelf-dev libudev-dev libpci-dev libiberty-dev autoconf llvm
$ apt-get source linux-image-unsigned-$(uname -r)
# Edited debian.master/changelog to set a local version
$ LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules clean
$ LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch
```

Note that `apt-get build-dep linux-image-$(uname -r)` (as suggested in the docs) fails because `linux-generate` is currently not installable but this appears to install all the required build tools.

This fails with:

```
Symlinking and copying Rust files for generic...
ln -s ../linux-lib-rust-6.5.0-14-generic/rust /home/tkcook/linux-6.5.0/debian/linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic/rust
Debug: module-check-generic
debian/scripts/checks/module-check "generic" \
    "/home/tkcook/linux-6.5.0/debian.master/abi/amd64" "/home/tkcook/linux-6.5.0/debian.master/__abi.current/amd64" 
II: Checking modules for generic...
    Reading modules to ignore...read 0 modules.
    Reading new modules...read 6595 modules.
    Reading old modules...read 6598 modules.
II: Checking for modules changes...
    MISS : spl
    MISS : v4l2loopback
    MISS : zfs
EE: Missing modules
make: *** [debian/rules.d/4-checks.mk:10: module-check-generic] Error 1
```

I'm not exactly clear what's going on here.  What list of modules is it comparing to?  Why is it complaining that those are missing?  Why are they missing?

Comment: For anyone coming after, removing these modules from `debian.master/abi/amd64/generic.modules` gets the build through this stage.  It still doesn't work, but it gets one step further on.

Answer (score 0):

Create ignore.modules under *ABI directory*:

```
touch debian.master/abi/amd64/ignore.modules
```

This worked in my case.